# How can I smooth my heatmap? (ggplot2, geom_tile())

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, heatmap, smoothing

I have created this sort of heatmap, but I need it to look smoother than like this [image]

code:

```
    ggplot(data = DF_with0, aes(V1, V2, fill = V3)) +                                                                           
     geom_tile() +
     xlab("X Coordinate (feet)") + ylab("Y Coordinate (feet)") +
     scale_fill_gradient(limits = c(0, 100), low = "black", high = "red") +
     scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
     scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

ideally I want it to look like this: [image]

Is there any fast way or library that I should know? Maybe I am missing something (I am quite noob).

My data frame looks like that:

[image]
Where the V1 and the x-axis, V2 the y-axis and V3 are the values for the color filling.

Thanks in advance to everyone!

Comment: Next time, provide a reproducible example instead of a screenshot of your dataset: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Try `geom_raster` with `interpolate = TRUE` instead of `geom_tile`.

Comment: In this way I am just blurring the image, not getting a better figure, sadly.

Comment: At some point the limit is just the resolution of your data. Example 2. you linked just includes significantly more data than example 1. and that's really all there is to it. Interpolation can help fill in the blanks but as you said it'll be blurry by nature.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you!